# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'lon' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, api

Initially it's showing the data but on searching its giving this error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'lon' of undefined".
please help!

```
const First = () => {
const [city, setcity] = useState(null);
const [search, setsearch] = useState("mumbai");
const [longitude, setlongitude] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchapi = async () => {
        const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&units=metric&appid={API_key}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const resjson = await response.json();
        console.log(resjson.coord.lon);
        setlongitude(resjson.coord.lon);
        setcity(resjson.main);

    }
    fetchapi();
}, [search]);

return (
    <div className="first">
        <div className="App">
            <h1>WEATHER APP 1</h1>
            <input type="search" className="input" value={search} onChange={(event) => { setsearch(event.target.value) }} />

            {!city ? (<p>no data found</p>) :
                (
                    <>
                        <div className="info">
                            <h2 className="location">{search}</h2>
                            <h3 className="temp">{city.temp}&deg; cel</h3>
                            <h3 className="minmx">Min : {city.temp_min}&deg; cel | Max : {city.temp_max}&deg; cel</h3>
                            <h1>des</h1>


                            <h4>longitude : {longitude}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}
export default First

Comment: Did you check what the value of search is between every fetchapi call? I am not sure but I think you might be calling it with every new letter that is typed in the search input.

Comment: yes that's what happening there